# SQL Get Duplicated based on all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MobileNo, COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, MobileNo;
```

Something like this will produce duplicates of the table `Customer` based on `FirstName`, `LastName` and `MobileNo`. However, I would like to produce a list of duplicates based on ALL columns (which are unknown). How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest you write a stored procedure that reads the table metadata and then constructs a dynamic sql statement. And are you using mysql, SQL Server, or both? You need to get your tags right.

Comment: SQL Server, I fixed the tags, thanks @MandyShaw

Comment: share your sample data and expected output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin The whole point of the question is making a query that works for any table, so sample data would be pointless.  I want to get all duplicate rows, easiest way I found to do this the above sample query, how I want it to work with unknown column names and base it off all the columns.

Comment: Use dynamic sql...

Comment: @testacc You should find the metadata you need in sys.all_objects and sys.columns.

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use checksum(*)

sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a33d/4

Ex.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA
  ( Field1 VARCHAR(10),
    Field2 VARCHAR(10)
  );

INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2','2');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2','2');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2','2');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('3','3');

SELECT TD1_CS.*
  FROM (SELECT TD1.*,
               CHECKSUM(*) CS1
          FROM TEST_DATA TD1
        ) TD1_CS
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT CHECKSUM(*) CS2
          FROM TEST_DATA TD2
         GROUP 
            BY CHECKSUM(*)
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) TD2_CS
    ON TD1_CS.CS1 = TD2_CS.CS2
```

Comment: Just be aware that there is a very very very slight chance that CHECKSUM(*) can return a false positive.   http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/08/19/checksum-weakness-explained.aspx

Comment: Thanks man,  that was an interesting post

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  FirstName, LastName, MobileNo, COUNT(*)
FROM    CUSTOMER
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, MobileNo
HAVING    COUNT(*) > 1
```